# Trouble clearing a specific form field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am having issues clearing a specific form field using JQuery. I am able to clear the entire form, but that is not what I desire.

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<article class="panel panel-default" id="<%= dom_id(list) %>">
  <div class="panel-heading"><%= list.name %><%= link_to %(<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>).html_safe, [:edit, list], remote: true %></div>

<%= form_tag(destroy_multiple_list_items_path(list_id: list.id),method: :delete,remote: true) do %>
  <ul class="list-group sortable" data-update-url="<%= sort_list_path(list) %>">
    <%= render list.items %>
  </ul>

  <div class="panel-footer">
    <%= submit_tag("Delete Selected",  :class => "btn btn-danger") %>
  </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="panel-footer">
    <%= form_for [list, Item.new], remote: true, html: { class: "form-inline", id: "#{dom_id(list)}_new_item_form" } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", id:itemName%>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Add Item", name: nil, class: "btn btn-defaultbtn"%>
    <% end %>

  </div>


</article>
```

I am trying to clear the last textfield which has an id of itemName.

I am clearing the form when I render the create view for the item, which would only be rendered upon successful commit of the item. Here is that JQuery

```
  $("#<%= dom_id(@list) %> ul").append("<%=j render 'items/item', item: @item %>");
$('#itemName').trigger("reset");
```

Now I was able to clear the form using

```
$("form").trigger("reset");
```

But that clears all form fields on the entire page, which includes checkboxes. The page contains multiple itemName inputs, and I know that this attempted method will clear ALL of them and not the specific one that was submitted, so I am open to any suggestions on clearing just the single specific itemName that was submitted, but if I can clear atleast only those fields and not the checkboxes as well that would be great.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: just a side note if you share this problem with the rendered `HTML` rather than server code concatenated, a more range of users might be able to help you as the actual problem is related to javascript

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `IDs`. There should be only one `#itemName`. (the `#` means `itemName` is an `id` not a `class`). Please paste the outputted HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably reach every element of the form by using the querySelectorAll DOM method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form input').forEach(function(element) {
  element.reset();
});
```

not sure how to perform it with jquery tho

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve the problem by grabbing the class .form-inline.

```
$(".form-inline").trigger("reset");
```

This resets just the text box and not the checkboxes. I appreciate all the help.